# Solution to SVG Render Bug in Safari?

Tags: svg, rendering, mobile-safari

I'm hoping there is some solution out there to this bug I keep running into. The nature of it is that .svg images will randomly render at a tiny fraction of their proper size. I had this bug a lot a couple of years back, but it seemed to be cleared up. However the site I'm working on now hits this bug hard. And since it's a mobile site, primarily for iPhones, it really has to work properly in Mobile Safari.

Here is a link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/op3u6uam/3/

If you click on the different "buttons" at the bottom of the rendered code result, they should change blue. I change the text with css, and I change the image by swapping the src attribute with a different image, one that is blue. Simple enough. But with SVG, the swapped images sometimes get messed up. The bug happens on desktop Safari too, so you can just click around the links to see it happen.

I'm hoping there is SOME way to bypass this bug. Something other than switching to raster images. Vector images have so many fantastic qualities, including the tiny size, which is really great when using the app with a poor cellular connection.

And now... this website insists I post the code, not just a link to the fiddle. Fair enough, if that's how you want it:

The HTML:

```
<body>
    ...
    <footer>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="odo"><img src="http://img.menulizard.com/odo.svg">Odometer</a>
            <li><a id="gas"><img src="http://img.menulizard.com/gas.svg">Gas</a>
            <li><a id="yum"><img src="http://img.menulizard.com/yum.svg">Meals</a>
            <li><a id="bus"><img src="http://img.menulizard.com/bus.svg">Misc</a>
            <li><a id="set"><img src="http://img.menulizard.com/set.svg">Settings</a>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
footer
{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
text-align: center;
border-top: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

footer a { display: block; }

footer li
    {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: .8em;
    }

footer img
    {
    fill: blue;
    height: 24px; width: 24px;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(function()
{
set_nav_bar("odo");

$("footer a").click(function($e)
    {
    $go_to = $(this).attr("id");
    set_nav_bar($go_to);
    $e.preventDefault();
    });

});

function set_nav_bar($go_to)
{
$("#odo img").attr("src","http://img.menulizard.com/odo.svg");
$("#gas img").attr("src","http://img.menulizard.com/gas.svg");
$("#yum img").attr("src","http://img.menulizard.com/yum.svg");
$("#bus img").attr("src","http://img.menulizard.com/bus.svg");
$("#set img").attr("src","http://img.menulizard.com/set.svg");
$("#odo,#gas,#yum,#bus,#set").css("color","");

$("#"+$go_to+" img").attr("src","http://img.menulizard.com/"+$go_to+".on.svg");
$("#"+$go_to).css("color","#0099ff");
}
```

Comment: How about using two `<img>` elements, one with each image, put them on top of each other (position: absolute) and adjust the opacity or z-index of the images so you see one or the other.

Comment: I suppose if I'm going that route, I can make it even simpler. Just put img tags one after the other, and show/hide the correct ones as needed. I'll try that if no better solution comes up. It may not even avoid the bug, it's so random. But hopefully it will.

Comment: I tried the dual-image technique but I seem to get other rending issues when I do that. Specifically, I get phantom spacing that nudge the "on" images so they aren't lined up with the "off" images. So THEN i tried using my original technique, but deleting and re-creating the entire image tags instead of just changing the "src". It works, without the tiny-svg render but. HOWEVER doing it this way causes a lot of slow, noticeable flicker in all of the images. It seems like every possible option comes with it's own unique bugs.

Comment: I tried switching to <object> tags instead of <img> tags, and that did seem to fix the rendering bug. That's nice, however, now there is a new bug. It would seem that <object> tags are unclickable. They don't pass click events to their parents, which breaks the navigation in a new way. If you click on the text, it works but not the icons: http://jsfiddle.net/op3u6uam/17/

Comment: make all the svg elements pointer-events: none

Comment: @RobertLongson That helped. Now my object tags are clickable and it mostly works without the rendering bugs. I say mostly because switching images in an object isn't quite as seemless as it is with an img tag. Meaning it flickers as it's switching. But this is a good baseline solution, and if something even better comes along, I'll switch to that. Thanks!

Comment: Is the only reason for changing the images to make them change color?

Comment: @firefoxuser_1 in this case, yes.